# Video will not play in JW Player on Android

Tags: android, flash, html, video, jwplayer

I cannot get [JW Player](http://www.longtailvideo.com/players/) to play anything on an Android device (real or emulated). In fact, even the default video and default setup that comes packaged in the JW Player [download](http://www.longtailvideo.com/players/jw-flv-player/) will not play! I've tried re-encoding the video... nope. I've tried prioritizing the HTML5 player over the Flash player... nope. I keep getting the error:

> Cannot play video
>
> Sorry, this video cannot be played.

Worth noting, it works fine on the web and in an iPhone.

**UPDATE:** Here's an example of the unmodified default player directly from the JW Player download: http://sambot.com/jw/. Try it on your Android...

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

where is your video file located? if it's located in your assets folder I think it won't run. try putting it in other directory like your sdcard or data folder

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Much as gilsaints88 said, playing from your assets folder in a WebView simply will not work.

I recently had this issue with jPlayer, and my immediate solution was to copy my audio/video content to the sdcard when the app is launched, then play it from there - this still has issues, of course, and in the long term I probably will just not use WebViews for playing audio.